# How connect my plugin translation to my page

Tags: plugins, translation

I have a problem. I am not very good at page making, but I use this plugin: https://sk.wordpress.org/plugins/booking-ultra-pro/
I wanted to translate it to my language, so I used Poedit and translated English version to my language (Slovak). I added my translated .po and .mo to language file. And what to do next? I guess it should be linked somewhere. Where and how? Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks a lot.

Eva

Answer (score 0):

> And what to do next? I guess it should be linked somewhere.

The plugin loads your language itself, so you don't need to do anything. However, it must be named correctly.

> I added my translated .po and .mo to language file.

Where and what are they named?

- For Slovak your MO file must be named `bookingup-sk_SK.mo`. *
- As for location. You can put this file inside the plugin's language folder but be warned that plugin updates will remove it!
- You can also place the file under `wp-content/languages/plugins/` but this location is not entirely safe either. Make sure you back your files up after making any translations.

---

* Note that this plugin does not follow WordPress conventions, which is why it has [no community translations](https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/sk/default/wp-plugins/booking-ultra-pro/). It should use the text domain "booking-ultra-pro" but instead uses "bookingup". That's fine as long as you know and as long as it loads itself, which it seems to do.

If you want any more help I'm going to need more details about what you've done and what isn't working. If you update your question, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I translated it, used the right name and put it into the right files, but it is still not working.
there are just few translated parts - which are possible to translate in plugin interface, but there are not translated buttons, and form labels. :-(